# ignore .css files in assetic lessphpfilter

Tags: php, css, less, assetic, minify

How can I make Assetic LessPhpFilter process only files with a specific extension (*.less) and ignore others (*.css). I'm using the below code to generate a combined css file

```
      $fm = new Assetic\FilterManager();
      $fm->set('less', new Assetic\Filter\LessphpFilter());

      $factory = new Assetic\Factory\AssetFactory(APP_ROOT.'stylesheets');
      $factory->setFilterManager($fm);

      $asset = $factory->createAsset($stylesheets, array('less'), array('debug' => false));
```

Comment: Can you add the info what your `$stylesheets`-var in the last line of your code contains?

Comment: $stylesheets is a list of files (both css and less) which need to be compiled and combined into a single file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the easiest way is to split the css and less files in separate folder.
Makes the folder a cleaner and you only have to load the folder where only less files in there.
The css files should be generated in a extra folder named css or something else.

I'm not sure what you really want to do but I think you would to merge this css files after generating it from the less file.

After the less file has been generated you have to make a second assetic tag where you include your new css from the less file and your existing one. This two gets automatic together to one single file with gets included.
Hope that helps or is a hint to find a solution for your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
$stylesheets = array('path/to/*.less');
$asset = $factory->createAsset($stylesheets, array('less'), array('debug' => false));
```

It should only load .less files

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used LessPhp Filter, but you could try something like

```
$file_details = pathinfo($file);
```

and then using

```
if($file_details['extension'] == ".less"){ //continue }
```